# Console doesn't read the input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

Using formik and react, I wanted to create a form and I wanted to increase the reusability of my components, so i made a component "TextInput.jsx" that I'm going to use during my whole project. Anyways when i type in the firstname field, the console doesn't log the changes, I have problems with passing the value props from the ContactForm component(parent Component) to the TextInput component(Child Component). Can anyone help me solve this problem. And thanks.

**ContactForm.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import TextInput from "../../shared/components/UIElements/TextInput";

const ContactForm = () => {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      firstName: "",
    },
  });
  console.log(formik);

 return (
    <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
      <div className="px-6 w-[700px]">
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cold-2 gap-8">
          <TextInput
            label="First Name"
            id="firstName"
            value={formik.values.firstName}
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
          >
            First name
          </TextInput>
          <div className="col-span-2 m-auto">
            <button
              className=" btn btn-primary w-32 align-middle"
              type="submit"
              onClick={
                () => console.log(formik)
              }
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

**TextInput.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
const TextInput = (props) => {
  const isRequired = props.required;
  const infoText = props.info;
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        placeholder={props.children}
        className="input input-primary input-bordered"
        id={props.id}
        value={props.value }
        onClick={() => props.onChange()}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it!

```
const TextInput = (props) => {
  const isRequired = props.required;
  const infoText = props.info;
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        placeholder={props.children}
        className="input input-primary input-bordered"
        id={props.id}
        value={props.value }
        onChange={props.onChange} // change this line
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```